# REST API did not process the context query parameter correctly- Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string, wordpress-rest-api

While working on my wordpress theme, inside my Site Health Status I am facing an error of

```
The REST API is one way that WordPress and other applications communicate with the server. For example, the block editor screen relies on the REST API to display and save your posts and pages.

The REST API did not process the context query parameter correctly.
```

Currently I am using Wp- version 6.2.

I have tried all possible methods to the best of my knowledge.

I am not able to understand what it is going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836808/woocommerce-setup-failed